# Allow users to highlight text in Titanium/ Alloy/ Appcelerator

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, titanium-alloy, appcelerator-alloy

Quick question. How can I allow users to highlight certain text in my Titanium app so that can copy and paste it.

I looked through the [Label Docs](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.Label) and couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a label. Must use a textfield.